# How to use ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback with ViewPager2?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager2, itemtouchhelper

I have created a image slider using `ViewPager2`, I need a functionality that when I swipe up  the image should be removed. I already worked with `RecyclerView`. So I remember I can use `ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback` for swipe to remove functionality. But `attachToRecyclerView` method requires a `RecyclerView` not a `ViewPager2` even though `viewpager2` uses RecyclerView adapter.

Kotlin:

```
ItemTouchHelper(object : ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.UP) {
    override fun onMove(
        recyclerView: RecyclerView,
        viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder,
        target: RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    ): Boolean {
        return false
    }

    override fun onSwiped(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, direction: Int) {

    }
}).attachToRecyclerView(binding.viewPager)
```

[image: viewpager2 slider]

Comment: Hi ZeroErr0r, I just updated the answer with another way for getting the `RecyclerView`. Please have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `RecyclerView` of the `ViewPager2` is not accessible by default, but you can enforce its accessibility using [reflection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/package-summary.html).

In that you need to access the `RecyclerView` by reflecting its declared field name using [`getDeclaredField()`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/class_getdeclaredfield.htm), and for `RecyclerView` it is: **mRecyclerView** (you can check it in the [`ViewPager2`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/androidx-collection-release/viewpager2/src/main/java/androidx/viewpager2/widget/ViewPager2.java) class)

Then use [`setAccessible()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/AccessibleObject.html#setAccessible-boolean-) to make this field accessible in order to allow using it for the `ItemTouchHelper`.

Here is an extension function to return the `ViewPager2` `ReyclerView`:

```
fun ViewPager2.getRecyclerView(): RecyclerView? {
    try {
        val field = ViewPager2::class.java.getDeclaredField("mRecyclerView")
        field.isAccessible = true
        return field.get(this) as RecyclerView
    } catch (e: NoSuchFieldException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    } catch (e: IllegalAccessException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
    return null
}
```

And you can use it like:

```
ItemTouchHelper(object : ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.UP) {
    override fun onMove(
        recyclerView: RecyclerView,
        viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder,
        target: RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    ): Boolean {
        return false
    }

    override fun onSwiped(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, direction: Int) {

    }
}).attachToRecyclerView(binding.viewPager.getRecyclerView())
```

Preview:

[image]

**UPDATE:**

Thanks to [@SimpleAndroid answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61465262/bottomsheetbehavior-with-viewpager2-cant-be-scrolled-down-by-nested-recyclervie/61857395#61857395), there is a nice way for obtaining the `RecyclerView`:

```
viewPager.children.find { it is RecyclerView }?.let {
    ItemTouchHelper(object : ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.UP) {
        override fun onMove(
            recyclerView: RecyclerView,
            viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder,
            target: RecyclerView.ViewHolder
        ): Boolean {
            return false
        }

        override fun onSwiped(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, direction: Int) {

        }
    }).attachToRecyclerView(it as RecyclerView)
}
```

Comment: How to pass the viewpager to attachToRecyclerView() in the SImpler method(SimpleAndroid answer)??

Comment: @ParthaPaul I just updated the answer, please have a look

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to get RecyclerView from ViewPager2. I assume you have an adapter named is PictureItemAdapter:

```
class PictureItemAdapter(private val recyclerViewAttached: (RecyclerView) -> Unit) : RecyclerView.Adapter<PictureItemViewHolder>() {

    override fun onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView: RecyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView)
        recyclerViewAttached(recyclerView)
    }
    ...
}
```

And you will receive the Recycler view from the `recyclerViewAttached` closure

```
val pictureItemAdapter = PictureItemAdapter{ recyclerView ->
    ItemTouchHelper(object : ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.UP) {
        override fun onMove(
            recyclerView: RecyclerView,
            viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder,
            target: RecyclerView.ViewHolder
        ): Boolean {
            return false
        }

        override fun onSwiped(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, direction: Int) {

        }
    }).attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView)
}
binding.viewPager.adapter = pictureItemAdapter
```

*Note: Both **RecyclerViewAdapter** and **FragmentStateAdapter** have a method onAttachedToRecyclerView.*